# How to prevent Laravel API from processing parameters on query-string?

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I would like to restrict my Laravel API from processing parameters as query-string when trying to authenticate the user. I've been trying with POSTMAN and all the time I'm able to get the token from my API whether I put the credentials on the body or as query-string in the url.

As per Laravel documentation I think that this is the behavior I want to avoid:

> [Retrieving Input Via Dynamic Properties](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests)
>
> You may also access user input using dynamic properties on the
>   Illuminate\Http\Request instance. For example, if one of your
>   application's forms contains a name field, you may access the value of
>   the field like so:
>
> `$name = $request->name;`
>
> **When using dynamic properties, Laravel will
>   first look for the parameter's value in the request payload. If it is
>   not present, Laravel will search for the field in the route
>   parameters.**

I'm using **Laravel 5.3** and **PHP 7.1.0**

Here is the POST by using query-string:

[image]

Here is the POST by using parameters in the body:

[image]

I have configured my CORS by using [laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors):

```
<?php

return [
   'defaults' => [
       'supportsCredentials' => false,
       'allowedOrigins' => [],
       'allowedHeaders' => [],
       'allowedMethods' => [],
       'exposedHeaders' => [],
       'maxAge' => 0,
       'hosts' => [],
   ],

   'paths' => [
       'v1/*' => [
           'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
           'allowedHeaders' => ['Accept', 'Content-Type'],
           'allowedMethods' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE'],
           'exposedHeaders' => ['Authorization'],
           'maxAge' => 3600,
       ],
   ],
];
```

My routes (the relevant ones):

```
Route::group(
    [
        'domain' => getenv('API_DOMAIN'),
        'middleware' => 'cors',
        'prefix' => '/v1',
        'namespace' => 'V1'
    ],
    function() {
        /* AUTHENTICATION */
        Route::post(
            'signin',
            'AuthenticationController@signin'
        )->name('signin');

        Route::post(
            'signup',
            'AuthenticationController@signup'
        )->name('signup');
    }
);
```

When listing my routes `php artisan route:list` I get:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Domain    | Method | URI           | Name       | Action                                                            | Middleware |
| localhost | POST   | api/v1/signin | api.signin | App\Http\Controllers\API\V1\AuthenticationController@signin       | api,cors   |
| localhost | POST   | api/v1/signup | api.signup | App\Http\Controllers\API\V1\AuthenticationController@signup       | api,cors   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My `AuthenticationController`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API\V1;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use App\Http\Requests;
use JWTAuth;

class AuthenticationController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('jwt.auth', ['except' => ['signin', 'signup']]);
    }

    public function signin(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        try {
            if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(
                    [
                        'error' => 'invalid_credentials'
                    ],
                    401
                );
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            return response()->json(
                [
                    'error' => 'could_not_create_token'
                ],
                500
            );
        }
        return response()->json(compact('token'));
    }

    public function signup(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $user = User::where(['email' => $request["email"]])->exists();
            if($user)
            {
                return Response::json(
                    array(
                        'msg' => "Email {$request->email} already exists"
                    ),
                    400
                );
            }
            $user = new User;
            $user->create($request->input());
            return Response::json(
                array(
                    'msg' => 'User signed up.'
                )
            );
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            return Response::json(
                array(
                    'success' => false,
                    'exception' => $exception
                )
            );
        }
    }
}
```

My `Kernel`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'jwt.auth' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken::class,
        'jwt.refresh' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\RefreshToken::class,
    ];
}
```

And I placed the respective configuration on `config/app.php`:

```
        ...
        /*
         * Package Service Providers...
         */
        Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider::class,
        Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
        Laracasts\Flash\FlashServiceProvider::class,
        Prettus\Repository\Providers\RepositoryServiceProvider::class,
        \InfyOm\Generator\InfyOmGeneratorServiceProvider::class,
        \InfyOm\CoreTemplates\CoreTemplatesServiceProvider::class,

        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

        Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider::class,
        Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider::class,
        Asvae\ApiTester\ServiceProvider::class,
    ],
```

**I don't want to use [dingoapi](https://github.com/dingo/api).**

I checked these resources:

- [JSON Web Token Tutorial: An Example in Laravel and AngularJS](https://www.toptal.com/web/cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs)
- [SERIES: BUILD AN APP WITH LARAVEL5 (BACKEND) AND ANGULARJS (FRONTEND) – PART 1](http://baljeetsingh.in/blog/series-build-an-app-with-laravel5-backend-and-angularjs-frontend-part-1-480/)

Last but not least, my `composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "v2.2.1",
        "laravelcollective/html": "v5.3.0",
        "infyomlabs/laravel-generator": "5.3.x-dev",
        "infyomlabs/core-templates": "5.3.x-dev",
        "infyomlabs/swagger-generator": "dev-master",
        "jlapp/swaggervel": "2.0.x-dev",
        "doctrine/dbal": "2.3.5",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "1.0.13",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.9",
        "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "v0.8.2",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "caouecs/laravel-lang": "3.0.19",
        "asvae/laravel-api-tester": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7",
        "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the answer given by "Basheer Ahmed" who pointed me in the right direction I ended up doing a Trait for parsing the `body` attributes that I want to get depending on the request:

```
<?php
namespace KeepClear\Traits\Controllers;

trait ApiRequest
{
    /**
     * Parse all attributes and return an array with the present values only.
     *
     * @param array $attributes
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return Array
     */
    public function parseBody($attributes, $request)
    {
        $params = [];
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            $value = $request->request->get($attribute);
            if ($value) {
                $params[$attribute] = $value;
            }
        }
        return $params;
    }
}
```

This method it will be used mostly on `create` and `update` actions like follows, on `AddressController`:

```
<?php

namespace KeepClear\Http\Controllers\API\V1;

...

use KeepClear\Traits\Controllers\ApiRequest;

...

class AddressController extends Controller
{
    use ApiRequest;

    /**
     * Instantiate a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('jwt.auth');
    }

    ...

    /**
     * Create address for the specified user.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param String $user_id
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function createUserAddress(Request $request, $user_id)
    {
        try {
            $attributes = ['city', 'county_province', 'zip_code'];
            $params = $this->parseBody($attributes, $request);
            User::find($user_id)->addresses()->create($params);
            return Response::json(
                array(
                    'message' => 'The address was successfully created.',
                    'success' => true
                )
            );
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            return Response::json(
                array(
                    'success' => false,
                    'exception' => $exception
                )
            );
        }
    }

    ...

    /**
     * Update address for the specified user.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param String $user_id
     * @param String $address_id
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function updateUserAddress(Request $request, $user_id, $address_id)
    {
        try {
            $attributes = ['city', 'county_province', 'zip_code'];
            $params = $this->parseBody($attributes, $request);
            Address::where(["user_id" => $user_id, "id" => $address_id])
                ->update($params);
            return Response::json(
                array(
                    'message' => 'The address was successfully updated.',
                    'success' => true
                )
            );
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            return Response::json(
                array(
                    'success' => false,
                    'exception' => $exception
                )
            );
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

In this way and by using `$request->request->get('my_param');` I can be sure after testing how that method works, that I'm only getting the attributes of the body.

This is the test for `AddressController` on those methods:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Api;

use Tests\TestCase;
...
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use Faker\Factory;
...

class AddressControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    use ApiTestTrait;
    use DatabaseMigrations;
    use WithoutMiddleware;

    ...
    public function testMethodCreateUserAddress()
    {
        $admin = factory(Role::class, 'admin')->create();
        $user = $admin->users()->save(factory(User::class)->make());
        $uri = 'api/v1/users/' . $user->id . '/addresses';
        $faker = Factory::create();
        $attributes = array(
            'city' => $faker->city,
            'county_province' => $faker->state,
            'zip_code' => $faker->postcode
        );
        $this->json('POST', $uri, $attributes)
            ->seeStatusCode(200)
            ->seeJsonEquals(
                [
                    'message' => 'The address was successfully created.',
                    'success' => true
                ]
            );
    }

    ...

    public function testMethodUpdateUserAddress()
    {
        $admin = factory(Role::class, 'admin')->create();
        $user = $admin->users()->save(factory(User::class)->make());
        $address = $user->addresses()->save(factory(Address::class)->make());
        $uri = 'api/v1/users/' . $user->id . '/addresses/' . $address->id;
        $attributes = array(
            'city' => 'newCity',
            'county_province' => 'newCountyProvince',
            'zip_code' => 'newZipCode'
        );
        $this->json('PUT', $uri, $attributes)
            ->seeStatusCode(200)
            ->seeJsonEquals(
                [
                    'message' => 'The address was successfully updated.',
                    'success' => true
                ]
            );
        $updated_address = Address::find($address->id);
        $this->assertEquals($updated_address->city, 'newCity');
        $this->assertEquals(
            $updated_address->county_province,
            'newCountyProvince'
        );
        $this->assertEquals($updated_address->zip_code, 'newZipCode');
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything that is appended to the url bar is considered a get request and will be available through `$_GET` super global variable. I assume that laravel `Request` request will merge both post and get request and then when you try to call any paramter that is sent through get or post, You can get it through

```
$request->myparam
```

But If you just try

```
$request->request->get('my_param');
```

You won't get the similar result.

:)

Comment: Hi there, I'm trying what you propose but this one "$request->request->post('my_param');" it doesn't work, the one that is working though, if this one "$request->request->get('my_param');". And also I'm checking "$request->getContent();" which is also returning only the parameters of the body, that is good! but with this method "$request->request->get('my_param');" I have write one per each parameter that I want to get from the request, not cool :P, and with this one "$request->getContent();" I have to parse the result since the method returns "email=nisevi%40gmail.com&password=password".

Comment: Do you know if the only way to get the parameters from the body are "$request->request->get('my_param');" and  "$request->getContent();" ?

Comment: Also I found an issue regarding how to get parameters from the body here https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/13585 just for adding a little more info...

Comment: @nisevi `$request->all()` will give a `key value` pair of all the request data...

Comment: Yes but that method also works if the parameters are in the URL... So if they are not in the Body goes to the URL and I don't want that... Anyways I'm using the method you suggested `$request->request->get('my_param');`  just please update your answer because the other one `post` it doesn't exist, and I will mark your answer as correct 